# Should I try to enforce encapsulation in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, encapsulation, idioms

Lets assume I have an object which has an maintains an array of items. When working with this object I would like to ensure that nobody can add items directly to the array but by only using the appropriate method. From the outside you can iterate the array and get items from it, but you should not be able to add items. If you need to add items you need to call an instance function `addItem`.

Javascript does not support this since exposing the Array object will enable anyone to add items to it.
With Typescript I can use a getter and return ReadOnlyArray type instead of Array type.
So my object could look like something like this:

```js
class SomeObject {
    #items: Array<string> = new Array<string>();

    get items() : ReadOnlyArray<string> {
        return #items;
    }

    addItem(item: string) {
        // do something special ...
        #items.push(item);
    }
}
```

Alternative is to simply expose the array as the property of the class:

```js
class SomeObject {
    
    items: Array<string> = new Array<string>();

    addItem(item: string) {
        // do something special ...
        items.push(item);
    }
}
```

I know that I'm not really encapsulating/hiding my array since ReadOnlyArray its only syntactic sugar but it could help to prevent someone accidentally using the object in the wrong way.

Is this worth the effort and should I pursue this approach or simply expose the array as a property?
To put the question more broadly: Should I try to enforce OOP encapsulation in Typescript/Javascript or should I simply ignore it because it is not idiomatic to Javascript?

Comment: In javascript if I see "_items" I would stay away from it, similarly, if #items was a private property then I would also stay away from it

Comment: Who is using your project, and from where? If everyone involved is expected to use typescript, then `ReadonlyArray` is enough. You just need a sign "don't do this" - if someone maliciously wants to break the code, there is little you can do anyways.

Comment: If there isn't anything special you need to do when pushing an item to the array, I would go for a public property. If you don't want somebody to push to the array, make it private or add a getter that returns a readonly array (both of which do not actually prevent adding to the array, but will stop misuse in the project for the most part)

Comment: Private property is ok

Comment: After reading the question a bit more - yes, you should use things like `ReadonlyArray` (lower case "o" btw). I just mentioned "it's enough", meaning "you don't need more", but the side you seem more interested in is "do i need this at all, should i do less?". You need a sign, which signals others (and yourself later, when you forgot), how to use it. That's the entire point of `protected`, `private`, `readonly`, etc - prevent anyone from accidentally doing something they aren't supposed to. Even in languages like java or c#, they just do that, they don't prevent `reflect` or similar.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks for the feedback but my question was more aimed on what is the 'standard' way to do things? It would make no sense for me to work like that in my project if everyone else is not doing it. Perhaps I'm missing something.